# How to modify less Files on server?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, less

I have some less files on my server which i want to modify. I tried to modify the `less` files i remove some code from files on server but it is still showing on front end. Can anyone tell me how to modify the `less` files on server. This is first time i am working on it. Any type of help will be appreciated.
E.g I have a code in back end

```
.container {
  max-width: @container-xs;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);
}
```

and it is showing like this in front end

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 75rem)
.container {
    max-width: 73.125rem;
}
```

But problem is when i removed this code from back end it is still showing me in front end. I also renamed the file but it didn't work for me

Comment: The `less` file surely compiles into a `.css` file that this actually exists in. Set up a less compiler on your machine so that when you edit the `less` file it auto saves and compiles into the corresponding `.css` file.

Comment: I think you should read up on what [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) is. Ditto'ing @Ohgodwhy that LESS is a preprocessor language that compiles out to CSS which is what the webpage is most likely serving.

Answer (score 0):

This could be two things. Most likely you need to compile you're Less Files into CSS. You can do this manually, or with a task runner like Gulp. If you already have compiled the file, it could be that the compiled css file is cached in the browser and the browser cache needs to be cleared. For relatively small CSS files you probably should set a shorter Cache time.

It is generally recommended to have a separate development environment than to work directly on the server. I would recommend setting up an environment similar to the server locally, and doing your testing there. This is also a good place to setup a build tool such as Gulp, Grunt or Webpack. These are all capable of automatically compiling your Less into CSS, as well minification, source maps, js concatenation etc.

Comment: I have already installed [prepo](https://prepros.io/downloads) in my pc and compile the less file into css file and make changes into css file but have no idea what to do next. Should i convert the css file again to less file or what

Comment: Once you have that css file, that is what you need to put up on the server. You can either ftp or use git to get the files up there. Just to clarify, browsers are incapable of parsing and reading Less. So you use you're preprocessor (which looks really nice actually. Reminds me of codekit) to convert it into CSS. That css file is what you send down from the server to the browser.